# php headers not working correctly under firefox

Tags: php

I'm using this header Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word;, but no use of it under firefox, it's downloading the file but without the extension. Why is that , is this some security that firefox has ?

Answer (score 5):

Firefox won't add a .doc to a downloaded file by itself, even if the mime-type indicates it's a word doc. It'll use the filename specified by the `Content-disposition` header:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="yourfile.doc"');
```